# yii2 frontend and backend uses different sessions

Tags: session, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Despite I did not separate sessions of frontend and backend apps on config files of those apps using `session => ...` option, my apps uses different sessions and when I login one of them then the other one is logouts. I could not find the source of problem. I want them using same session. What can be the problem?

Comment: Please post your Config and Controller code

Comment: It takes very bad format when I copy here config files, now I don t have much time, I will copy later, but I don t use session option in any config file (common, frontend, bakcend). On remote server it works well, there is a problem with apache server I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

Add `session` in **frontend->config->main.php**

```
'components' => [
    'session' => [
        'name' => 'PHPFRONTSESSID',
        'savePath' => sys_get_temp_dir(),
    ],
]
```

same in **backend->config->main.php**

```
'components' => [
    'session' => [
        'name' => 'PHPBACKSESSID',
        'savePath' => sys_get_temp_dir(),
    ],
]
```

Comment: Thanks vishu, now it does not logout when login other one but they again using separate sessions, when I login one of app the other one does not login, I need to login them separately. I also uses `$_SESSION` variable on some external php files. Since this problem I cannot pass some variables through session variable.

Comment: refer this link http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/814/guide-how-to-actually-separate-frontend-user-and-backend-admin-on-yii2-advanced/